# if class contains class ___ then remove text between <a></a>

Tags: javascript

I want to remove text between `<a href="#" class="main_navigation-mobile-logo">text</a>` when in  `<ul class="main_navigation-menu js-main_navigation-menu">` will be toggled class .main_navigation-menu--open so when it will be looking like this there: `<ul class="main_navigation-menu js-main_navigation-menu main_navigation-menu--open">` i want to delete that text between a (it displays only in 991px max width)

JS:

```
const menuMobile = document.querySelector(".js-main_navigation-menu");

function myFunction(x, y) {
    if (x.matches && y.matches) {
        $('.main_navigation-mobile-logo').html('');
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)");
var y = menuMobile.classList.contains("main_navigation-menu--open");

myFunction(x, y);
x.addEventListener(myFunction);
y.addEventListener(myFunction);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="main_navigation-menu js-main_navigation-menu">
                <li>...</li>
               <button>...</button>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="main_navigation-mobile-logo">text</a>
```

Whats wrong with the code? It does not work.

Comment: I write an other answer with CSS that remove text when menu is open

Comment: Use ```element.classList.contains(class);``` then ```element.innerText = '';``` (pure JS, no jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// when screen is max-width 991px
if ($(window).width() <= 991) {

  $('#toggle').on('click', function () {
      $('.main_navigation-menu').toggleClass('main_navigation-menu--open');
      $('.main_navigation-mobile-logo').toggle();
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">click me for toggle</button>
<ul class="main_navigation-menu js-main_navigation-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <button>...</button>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="main_navigation-mobile-logo">text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .main_navigation-menu--open + a { //select the adjacent sibling
      font-size: 0; 
    }
}
```

So when it's open the text disapear

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to manipulate text

```
function myFunction(x, y) {
if (x.matches && y.matches) {
    $('.main_navigation-mobile-logo').innerHTML = '';
}
```